# How can I improve this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, loops

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
    switch (i) {
        case 3:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 12:
        case 18:
            console.log("Fizz");
            break;

        case 5:
        case 10:
        case 20:
            console.log("Buzz");
            break;

        case 15:
            console.log("FizzBuzz");
            break;

        default:
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

I am supposed to print numbers from 1-20.

These are the conditions.

if a number is divisible by 3, then i need to print "Fizz"

If a number is divisible by 5, then I need to print "Buzz"

if a number is divisible by both 3 and 5, then I need to print "FizzBuzz".

I came up with the aforementioned code, but I think it can be improved.

Comment: You can use the modulo operator (`%`) and if statements to do this more cleanly (an infinitely scalable, i.e. your code won't work if you change 20 to, say, 100).

Comment: you only need 2 `if()` statements for those conditions and concatenate  a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the modulus operator (%), this will help make your code future proof, should the 20 need to change to 200 etc

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
    if(i % 5  == 0 && i % 3  == 0) {
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    } else if (i % 5  == 0) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    } else {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```